# Mapserver INCLUDE using multiple .map files

Tags: raster, mapserver, mapping, mapfile, ms4w

I am currently testing out a new way to display my Mapserver WMS's. Here is the context. I have a script that generates an individual .map file for each of my rasters. These mapfiles are fully functioning with their own Link, extent, layers, legends, etc... I'd like to combine two of the .map files into a "combined" .map file. I've been playing around with the INCLUDE call where I reference 2 of my generated .map files.

something like this:
MAP
..
INCLUDE 'Raster1.map'
INCLUDE 'Raster2.map'
...
END

This seems to work however mapserver is ONLY displaying the data for the first INCLUDE, NOT the second. Is there any way where I can get it to read both INCLUDEs?

Comment: I guess that your Raster1.map contains one END too much and Raster2.map is never read.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just for clarification, map 1 and map 2 are interchangeable. If I put map 2 as the first INCLUDE, it will only show map 2 and not map 1.

Comment: Can you add details of your map files, rather than a basic structure.    When you have both together, do you see any error when doing a  WMS GetCapabilities request?

Comment: Map1 vs map2 behavior is expected. If both mapfiles are complete they include also the closing END and the next mapfile is never parsed. If it was it would probably not work because the once-in-a-mapfile elements like MAP-WEB would be repeated. But perhaps MapServer should give you a warning about extra text found after the final END. See https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/issues/2922.

Answer (score 1):

INCLUDE inserts the contents of the file textually; the effect is the same as if you had just concatenated your two .map files. This does not result in a syntactically valid map file.

What you should do is to have two include files that contain just the LAYER clause for each raster, and then three map files that incldue the first, the second, or both.
(If these three map files have common code, you can move that into include file(s), too.)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up using and it is working well!

Answer (score 1):

Certainly it is doable, to have one map file include multiple others, and for those map files to also have includes.

For example the below is the start of a map file for a WMS/WFS/WCS service:

```
MAP
    CONFIG "MS_ERRORFILE" "C:/LOGS/mapserver/tst/argi/error.log"
    CONFIG "PROJ_LIB" "C:/apps/gisinternals/bin/proj/SHARE"
    DEBUG 1
    # EXTENT: Rough extent of Uganda in EPSG:4326
    EXTENT 29 -2 37 4.5
    FONTSET "../DefaultMapIncludes/fontset.lst"
    IMAGEQUALITY 95
    INCLUDE "../DefaultMapIncludes/BGS-service-std-output.map"

    INCLUDE "infrastructure.map"
    INCLUDE "project.map"
    INCLUDE "energy.map"
    INCLUDE "minerals.map"
    INCLUDE "geology.map"
    INCLUDE "landuse.map"
    INCLUDE "admin.map"
    INCLUDE "parentmaterial.map"
    INCLUDE "relief.map"
    INCLUDE "lvbath.map"
    INCLUDE "popn.map"

    LEGEND
        IMAGECOLOR 255 255 255
        STATUS ON
        KEYSIZE 18 12
        LABEL
            TYPE BITMAP
            SIZE MEDIUM
            COLOR 0 0 89
        END
    END
    MAXSIZE 3072
    NAME "UGA_ARGI_PILOT"
    PROJECTION #Default SERVICE projection
        "init=epsg:4326"
    END
    SHAPEPATH "data"
    SIZE 600 800
    STATUS ON
    SYMBOLSET "../DefaultMapIncludes/symbols.sym"
#====================================================================#
# Start of web interface definition (including WMS enabling metadata)
#====================================================================#
    WEB
        HEADER "tmpl/query_header.htm"
        FOOTER "tmpl/query_footer.htm"
        IMAGEPATH "C:/WxS/ms/apps/test/ARGI_UPP/www/out/"
        IMAGEURL "/ms_tmp/"
        METADATA
           ...
```

And this service is definitely working, giving

> WCS ~ http://ogc2.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/UGA_ARGI/ows?service=WCS&request=GetCapabilities&
>
> WMS ~ http://ogc2.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/UGA_ARGI/ows?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&
>
> WFS ~ http://ogc2.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/UGA_ARGI/ows?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities&